# Why is the _ENV of a function that's called inside a function compiled by load() using _G as its _ENV and not the env arg that was provided to load()?

Tags: lua, environment

*Lua 5.4.4*

When I call a function `is_env_g()` from inside a Lua chunk that was compiled from a string using `load()` that has a different environment provided to `load()`'s `env` argument, the `is_env_g()` function doesn't use the `env` argument as its `_ENV`.

Observe the following code:

```
-- create a new table with the parent's variables available via the __index metakey
function new_env(parent)
  return setmetatable({}, {
    __index = parent
  })
end

function run_lua_string(luastr, env)
  local f = load(luastr,  '', 't', env) -- compile luastr using env as the first upvalue (_ENV)
  f()                                   -- run the compiled luastr
end

function is_env_g()
  print(_ENV == _G)
end

local luastr = 
[[
  print(_ENV == _G) -- prints 'false' as expected
  is_env_g()        -- I expect 'false' but receive 'true' - why?
]]

-- prepare a new env; this one "inherits" from _ENV, which in this case is also _G, but it is *not* equal to _G
local env = new_env(_ENV)

-- compile and run luastr in the env we created above
run_lua_string(luastr, env)
```

When I compile and run the Lua code string `luastr` with `run_lua_string`, the `print(_ENV == _G)` line inside `luastr` prints `true`, as expected. However, when this same line (`print(_ENV == _G)`) is run inside another function, `is_env_g()`, which itself is called from within that compiled `luastr` chunk, I receive `false`.

It seems that the `is_env_g()` function does not have the `env` arg that was provided to `load()` as its `_ENV` upvalue - why is this?

How might this be modified so that `is_env_g()` uses the `_ENV` that is provided to `load()`'s `env` argument? I know we could modify it to explicitly pass `luastr`'s `_ENV` likeso:

```
function is_env_g(env)
  print(env == _G)
end

local luastr = 
[[
  is_env_g(_ENV)
]]
```

Is there another way without passing the `_ENV` as an argument like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define your `is_env_g`, the `_ENV` gets bound and the value persists even in the "string chunk". Since you do not have `_ENV` defined anywhere it is set to `_G` when binding. See [2.2 - Environments and the Global Environment](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.2) for detailed explanation.

You can check it with the [`debug.getupvalue()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-debug.getupvalue):

```lua
function is_env_g()
    print(_ENV == _G)
end

print(debug.getupvalue(is_env_g, 1))  --> _ENV    table: 0x5583f6f84c50
local luastr = "print(debug.getupvalue(is_env_g, 1))"
run_lua_string(luastr, env)  --> _ENV    table: 0x5583f6f84c50
```

You can observe what happens in the function step-by-step with **luac**(1):

```
$ luac -l -l env.lua
...
function <env.lua:13,15> (9 instructions at 0x561c7bb38850)
0 params, 3 slots, 1 upvalue, 0 locals, 2 constants, 0 functions
        1       [14]    GETTABUP        0 0 0   ; _ENV "print"
        2       [14]    GETUPVAL        1 0     ; _ENV
        3       [14]    GETTABUP        2 0 1   ; _ENV "_G"
        4       [14]    EQ              1 2 1
        5       [14]    JMP             1       ; to 7
        6       [14]    LFALSESKIP      1
        7       [14]    LOADTRUE        1
        8       [14]    CALL            0 2 1   ; 1 in 0 out
        9       [15]    RETURN0
constants (2) for 0x561c7bb38850:
        0       S       "print"
        1       S       "_G"
locals (0) for 0x561c7bb38850:
upvalues (1) for 0x561c7bb38850:
        0       _ENV    0       0
```

Since the `_ENV` will bind when you define the function, you'll need to move the definition; a simple way to accomplish it looks like this:

```lua
local env = new_env(_ENV)
do
    local _ENV = env
    function is_env_g() ... end  -- It's only available in `env` now.
end
```

You can also put similar snippet somewhere into `run_lua_string` just make sure to have `_ENV` with a proper value before you define the function. Alternatively, you can forcibly modify it with [`debug.setupvalue`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-debug.setupvalue):

```lua
local env = new_env(_ENV)
debug.setupvalue(is_env_g, 1, env)
run_lua_string(luastr, env)  --> false false
```

Question would be, why do you need it? The proper solution or complete back off depends on the answer.

Comment: My use-case is I have a module as part of the `env` I pass to `load()` that may execute a member function wherein `new_env(_ENV)` is called, which I had hoped would use the chunk's `_ENV`. I'm avoiding explicitly passing the chunk's `_ENV` as a direct argument to the member method. What I'll probably do is just store the `env` as a member variable of an instance of the module I pass to `env` and instead call something like `new_env(self.chunk_env)`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @VoodooJuJu How about loading that module into new environment as part of environment setup (rather than inheriting the loaded module through metatable)? This way you move the definition and it binds to the target environment.

Comment: That actually sounds better, I'll do that.